# SwiftUI Text stops wrapping lines when padding is added

Tags: macos, swiftui, macos-monterey

In the code below, running on macOS 12.4, I'm trying to display a `sheet` with a few stacked `Text` views. As shown in the screenshot, the last line is not wrapping. Strangely, if I had a padding on the `Text` two views *above* it (see comment in code), that triggers something, and the `Text` wraps. This seems bizarre and buggy to me, so I don't think I can rely on it.

Can anyone explain this behavior, and suggest a way to ensure the text wraps instead of truncates?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Test Sheet") {
                showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 300)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            TestSheet {
                showSheet = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestSheet: View {
    let dismiss: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                let msg = "Longer message. Blah blah blah blah blah, blah blah blah blah, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah, blah blah."
                Text("Delete?").font(.title).padding(8).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                Text(verbatim: msg) 
                   // .padding(.top, 6) <-- uncomment this and it works. ???
                Text("Do you want to delete them?").padding(.top, 6)
                Text(verbatim: "They can be undeleted later, until you 'Purge Deleted Items'.")
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .padding(.top, 6)
            }
            .padding()
            Divider()
            HStack {
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { dismiss() }
            }.padding()
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
    }
}
```

Screenshot of it not wrapping as desired:

[image]

Comment: Instead of `Text(verbatim:` use just `Text()` and it lays out strings independently of padding.

Comment: I'm not seeing that. I just removed both `verbatim:`s and re-ran. No change in behavior.

Comment: Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.4 - works well.

Comment: 13.4.1 and 12.4 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tagging the following to the end of your `Text` view:

`.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`

I know it looks counter-intuitive, 'I want my vertical size fixed rather than my horizontal size fixed, don't I?', but the text view gives its 'ideal' width as its non-wrapped (i.e. single line) width. Therefore, you need to ignore that, but insist on its now wrapped vertical ideal size instead.

Comment: That did work. But I don't really understand why. I would have guessed that `x.padding(...)` would create a larger view around `x`, not take a chunk out `x` to get the padding. But this sounds like it's doing the latter here.

Comment: Yeah, its confusing and mixed in with how VStack lays itself out. VStack seems to ask each contained element its ideal size in a first pass, then once it has these dimensions, offers each each flexible view an equal proportion of the total amount. So you'll see if you add a `Colour.red` and a `Cooler.green` in there, they'll get an equal slice of pie to the Text views without the `fixedSize` modifier.

Comment: Also, remember that `padding` isn't creating any more space for the text to breath, if anything it's wrapping a fixed size around the view which is constraining the available space further. However, as VStack asks the total size of *all* the views during layout, this ends up boosting the amount of space the view is then offered in the final pass.